# Spock testing: Too many invocation

Tags: spock

I wrote service for manual  requeuing events from one queue to another.

```java
public class ReQueueService {
  private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  public void retry() {
    InfoLog infoLog;
    while (rabbitTemplate != null && 
      (infoLog = (InfoLog) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(EVENT_WAITING_FOR_REQUEUE)) != null
    ) {
      rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(SOME_QUEUE, infoLog.getSomeEvent());
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is getting:

```
Too many invocations for:

1 * rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(SOME_QUEUE, _ as SomeEvent) >> {
      arguments ->
        assert infoLog.getSomeEvent() == arguments[1]
    }   (2 invocations)

Matching invocations (ordered by last occurrence):

2 * rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(SOME_QUEUE, ...
```

while my code in test looks like this:

```groovy
class ReQueueServiceTest extends Specification {
  def "should resend single event to some queue" () {
    given:
    InfoLog infoLog = Fixtures.createInfoLog()
    def rabbitTemplate = Mock(RabbitTemplate){
      receiveAndConvert(EVENT_WAITING_FOR_REQUEUE) >> { infoLog }
    }
    ReQueueService reSyncService = new ReQueueService(rabbitTemplate)

    when:
    reSyncService.retry()

    then:
    1 * rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(SOME_QUEUE, _ as SomeEvent) >> {
      arguments ->
        assert infoLog.getSomeEvent() == arguments[1]
    }
  }
}
```

The question is why I have 2 invocations, if I stubb only one event?

EDIT:

link to repo with example: https://gitlab.com/bartekwichowski/spock-too-many

Comment: It is hard to reason about invisible code. There is a `while` loop of which I cannot know how many iterations will be executed (obviously 2) because the code snippets you provide are incomplete. I cannot copy and run them. There are so many dependencies missing, e.g. `Fixtures`, `RabbitTemplate`, `SomeEvent`, `InfoLog`. Also the constants or enum values you use such as `SOME_QUEUE`, `EVENT_WAITING_FOR_REQUEUE` are missing. If I cannot reproduce your problem, I cannot help you. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and then provide one. Thank you.

Comment: link to repo added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the repo link. As soon as I could run the test and inspect the behaviour live, it was pretty easy to find out what was wrong. First I will make an educated guess about what you actually want to test:

1. The mock's `receiveAndConvert` method should return `str` when it is called first and then `null` when called again.
2. Subsequently you want to verify that the `while` loop runs exactly 1 iteration, i.e. that `convertAndSend` is called with exactly the parameters you expect.

This can be achieved by

1. `receiveAndConvert("FOO") >>> [str, null]`
2. `1 * rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("BAR", str)` (no need for ugly assertions inside a stubbed method, the parameters are verified against your parameter constraints already)

If I refactor your specification a little bit for prettier variable names and less verbosity, it looks like this:

```groovy
class ReSyncServiceTest extends Specification {
  def "should resend single event to resource sync queue"() {
    given:
    def message = "someValue"
    def rabbitTemplate = Mock(RabbitTemplate) {
      receiveAndConvert("FOO") >>> [message, null]
    }

    when:
    new ReSyncService(rabbitTemplate).retry()

    then:
    1 * rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("BAR", message)
  }
}
```

---

P.S.: Your version with the assertion inside does not return anything explicitly, but implicitly the result of the last assertion. Be careful with that. With `>> { ... }` you are stubbing the method result! It would always return `true` in the version you have in Git and the test only terminates because you added the `1 *` limit. If it was not there, you would have an endless loop. Your code did not do what you thought it did. Maybe the Spock manual can help you there. :-)

---

P.P.S.: Maybe you want to refactor your application code to be a bit easier to understand and maintain and to be a little less "smart". Also there is no need to check that `rabbitTemplate != null` in every iteration, once should be enough. How about this?

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReSyncService {
  private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  public void retry() {
    if (rabbitTemplate == null)
      return;
    String event;
    while (null != (event = getEventFromQueue()))
      rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("BAR", event);
  }

  protected String getEventFromQueue() {
    return (String) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("FOO");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note my two updates with "P.S." and "P.P.S.".